# C++17 How to save a generic callable for later use

Tags: c++, generics, stl, c++17, callable

I want to save a generic callable with its state for later use. Please see the example code bellow. I could probably use `std::function` or `std::bind` to achieve this but I do not know what is best. Also please note that in the `main()` of the example below, the `capturedInt` must be saved in the state of the callable.

What are the possibilities for:

- `makeCallable(fun, args...) { ... }`
- `CallableType`

```
template <typename RetT>
class Service
{
public:

   template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
   Service(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args)
   {
      m_callable = makeCallable(fun, args...);
   }

   Run()
   {
      m_callable();
   }

   CallableType<RetT> m_callable;
};

// Template deduction guides (C++17)
template <typename Fn, typename... Args>
Service(Fn&& fun, Args&&... args) -> Service<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<Fn>, std::decay_t<Args>...>>;

int main()
{
   Service* s = nullptr;
   {
      int capturedInt = 5;
      s = new Service([capturedInt]() { std::cout << capturedInt << std::endl; } );
   }
   
   s->Run();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also use `std::function`, but leave it as the interface to the class, like this:

```
template <typename RetT>
class Service
{
public:

   Service(std::function<RetT()> fun)
   {
      m_callable = std::move(fun);
   }

   Run()
   {
      m_callable();
   }
private:
   std::function<RetT()> m_callable;
};
```

Then you're explicit about the options to store callables for the class. The user can then decide how to bind their arguments to the callable themselves, which with std::function is flexible.

```
s = new Service([capturedInt]() { std::cout << capturedInt << std::endl; } );
s->Run();
```

or

```
struct Foo
{
    void MyPrint(int capturedInt) { std::cout << capturedInt << std::endl; }
};
Foo foo;
int capturedInt = 5;
s = new Service(std::bind(&Foo::MyPrint, &foo, capturedInt);
s->Run();
```

. Then you don't have to worry about life time problems caused by the class.

Answer (score 1):

Given the setup, your only option for `m_callable` would be an `std::function`. Since the type of the functor is an argument to the constructor itself, you'd have to type-erase the functor to save it for future use - and `std::function` is just a mechanism for this.

As a result, `m_callable` would be:

```
std::function<retT ()> m_callable;
```

and you would set it like that:

```
m_callable = [=]() { return fun(args...); }
```

Comment: Why not use `auto`?

Comment: While I agree with std::function being the only type if `Fn` and `Args...` can differ for one return type, your construction of `m_callable` does not make use of perfect forwarding. For example, you couldn't pass a move-only type like `str::unique_ptr`. I would actually use `std::bind` since perfect forwarding arguments and the function for a call and through a lambda capture is non-trivial. But `m_callable = std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fun), std::forrward<Args>(args)...);` should work like a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `std::function<>` and `std::bind`, there's a pattern called continuation passing. The benefit is, you can also save a generic lambda, something that wouldn't work with the former two; the price you pay is, you need to wrap the rest of the code in a lambda:

```
template<typename Cont>
void get_plus2_cps(Cont cont) {
    auto plus2 = [&](auto n) { return n + 2; };
    cont(plus2);
}

// usage:
int main() {
    // some code
    get_plus2_cps([&](auto plus2) {
        // rest of the code here
        std::cout << plus2(2) << ' ' << plus2(2.0) << std::endl;
    };
    // no code here
}
```